# view disappears on dragging it over framelayout android

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, view

I am implementing drag and drop of view in app. I have a frameLayout and a view inside it. I want to drag that view horizontally. I can drag that view but when I release it, the view gets disappears. Here is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:id="@+id/chart"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
<View
    android:id="@+id/drag_line"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="#FF0000FF" />
```

Here is my drag and drop event handlers

```
layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
line = (View) findViewById(R.id.drag_line);
  activity.line.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                activity.line.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, null, 0);
                activity.line.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
    activity.layout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {

            int currentX = (int) event.getX();

            //FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED){
                Log.d(TAG, "STARTED");
                y = (int) event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            if(event.getAction() == DragEvent.ACTION_DROP){
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                Log.d(TAG, "Drop");
                int x_cord = (int) event.getX();
                Log.d(TAG, "Drop X"+x_cord);
                Log.d(TAG, "Drop Y"+y);
                params.leftMargin = x_cord;
                params.topMargin = y;

                // line.setY(x_cord);
                //layout.removeAllViews();
                activity.line.setLayoutParams(params);
                activity.line.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I can see in my log that I have x and y coordinates but the line get disappears instead to be on that coordinates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup your drag events like this -

```
findViewById(R.id.topHalf).setOnDragListener(new ColonyHutDrag());
```

Where R.id.topHalf is id of my Framelayout and ColonyHutDrag is class which implements onTouchListener

```
public class ColonyHutClick implements OnTouchListener
```

When a dragged object is released that doesn't have an OnDragListener set, there is nothing to handle the ACTION_DROP, and you therefore don't get an opportunity to reset the dragged View to VISIBLE.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: sorry can you explain it in bit details, what is R.id.topHalf here and ColonyHutDrag...

Comment: Thanks let me try it...I accept the answer if it works

Comment: When I do like this it throw exception on drop java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams